# Repository Pattern in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design

I am going to implement repository pattern to my project using Node.js, I am new to DDD, but I have read a lot of it. I understand repository pattern should be keep simple and deals with aggregate.

But I am wondering how should I load entity relations? in **ORM** we usually have eager loading and lazy loading. But since Nodejs retrieve data asynchronously, I think lazy loading is not possible.

Should I encapsulate eager inside the repository? or is it better if I make a parameter to define what relations to be included?

For example:

```
class GenericRepository {
  find({ select, where, includes, orderBy }) {
    // Code
  }
}
```

If i define a method like that, isn't it like reinventing **ORM** function?
Please give me your opinions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In DDD there is not such thing as lazy loading an Aggregate or parts of it. Before executing a command, the Aggregate must be fully loaded from the Repository. If you feel that in most cases it does not need to be fully loaded maybe your Aggregate boundaries are wrong and you have an Aggregate that is too big.

Regarding the Aggregate repositories in JavaScript, the simplest solution is to use a document database like MongoDB that persist an JavaScript object as it is, with minimum number of transformations.

For read (or display) scenarios, you can load only some attributes of the Aggregate but be careful to not break the Aggregate encapsulation as you start to depend on Aggregate internal properties.

The things are simpler (from this perspective) in CQRS architectures because the Aggregate corresponds only to the write-model and you can have any number of perfect-fitted/optimized read-models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! what is the solution for the aggregate that is too big? Should I skip using read method in repository for big aggregate? A random example: **Order -> Order Detail -> Item -> Supplier -> City -> Country**, 
**Order -> Customer -> City -> Country**

Comment: @Hakutsuru why do you have such a "complete" Customer in the Order Aggregate? A `CustomerID` should suffice

Comment: I see, so in order to get the complete customer I need to fetch it from CustomerRepository?

Comment: @Hakutsuru yes, the *rule* is that you add information from other Aggregates only if they are used by the local Aggregate to enforce the rules or to express relations, not to help you in displaying information to the end user; you *may* do it but don't cry that the Aggregate is too big.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i am clear with the implementation of repository and the collection like concept. So to displaying complex information to end user is it better using CQRS or even raw query?

Comment: @Hakutsuru CQRS is perfect for splitting the write/command from the read/query/display models